# How to move a div with a dynamically added class name

Tags: javascript, html, css

So currently in class we are trying to make a 15-puzzle using ONLY Javascript, CSS, and basic HTML. I am also not allowed to modify the html at all, fun stuff. Anyway, I was able to add dynamic class names to my html and reference them in the css as follows:

```
var children = document.getElementById("puzzlearea").childNodes;

//iterates through all children
    for (child in children) {

        //if children is a div then we do something to it
        if (children[child].nodeName == "DIV") {
            //add a class that corresponds to a css to the current div child that we are on
            children[child].classList.add('a' + i);
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
```

In our CSS then we are able to reference it by simply stating .a15 and assigning it the required margin, size, image positioning, and all. However, when I try to move it by referencing its id using document.getElementById(".a15").style.top = "200px" -- or just "a15" -- it does not work. The above mentioned way is the suggestions I have seen on stack in order to move divs.

Currently I am trying something as follows:

```
 document.getElementsByTagName('div')[15].onclick = function () {
            alert("work"); //does actually only happen on correct div
            this.style.top = "500px" //still doesn't move it
    }
```

However, with this it still does not move it, and of course fetches all divs. As such, the question still stands: "How to move divs with dynamically added class names?

Edit: Got it to move by also mentioning that the position should be relative in the CSS, however I can still only reference it in the above mentioned way and not via direct iD.

Comment: can you provide a sample fiddle stating your problem?

Comment: I would love to...but ya know, academic work.

Comment: If 'a15' is a class name, use document.getElementsByClassName('a15')[0] instead of getElementById. Top and left property only works with CSS "position: absolute;" https://jsfiddle.net/unj1njt7/

Comment: I see, it does move with relative using the snippet posted above as well however interestingly enough.

Answer (score 3):

You are adding `class` to those div(s), so when you are referencing them instead of:

```
document.getElementById(".a15").style.top ...
```

it should be:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("a15").style.top ... // without .
```

Note that **`getElementsByClassName`** returns array of elements which has that certain class. So you may have to do something like

```
var currentDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("a15")[0] // assuming you have only one div with class a15
// then
currentDiv.style.top ...
```

*working example just in case: https://jsfiddle.net/Laf54y1a/3/*

Comment: see, that's what I thought, but that doesn't work. neither of those two options work

Comment: alas, in a world where things make sense that should work, sadly this is not such a world. Which is most confusing as we can clearly reference it in the CSS like a normal class.